# Run Scenarios with time constrain on Jenkins using ruby cucumber framework

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber, rake

I have two scenarios, scenario 1 should run at 5:00 PM everyday. Gather the DB results from it and save it on yaml file. I have to use these results to run scenario 2 which needs to be run next day at 8AM. How can I implement this on Jenkins. 
Write now I am trying to implement through rake task. My logic is if the yaml file is present run scenario 2 or else run scenario 1.
Is there a better way to do it?
I need these two scenarios on the same jenkins job.

Comment: Do you actually want to run the scenarios 15 hours apart in real time, or pretend to do things with that time gap?

Comment: I need to run scenario 1 before a job flow and scenario2 after the flow. i kind of wrote if else statement within the rake task to make it work.